# Localhost - PHP Include Not Showing Errors

Tags: php, include, localhost, directoryindex

I've just installed the latest version of Appserv ( 9.3.0 ), which includes:

```
Apache 2.4.41
PHP 7.3.10
MySQL 8.0.17
phpMyAdmin 4.9.1
```

I'm using Localhost as my root directory and trying to reuse old files to build a new website, but I'm noticing a problem.

I'm using the `include()` function, but there is a problem.

`<?php include(file.php); ?>` shows the contents of `file.php`, but, if I delete `file.php`, it doesn't give me an error message saying `file.php could not be found`. Why is this?

Comment: Do you have error reporting and displaying enabled on the server? Have you checked the server error logs?

Comment: I don't know. I had an old version of appserv and everything worked fine, this new version isn't doing what I expected. How do I even enable error reporting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Not really @jrswgtr - Most logical seems to be to set `display_errors = on` in php.ini, but I've tried this and it's still not working.

Comment: Ignore that. I removed `error_reporting(1);` and it's now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to secondly:

`include()` on a non-existent file produces an error of type `E_WARNING`. For testing purposes simply add this line of code

```
error_reporting(1);
```

before using an `include()` statement.

For production you should avoid displaying any kind of errors. You can register your own error handler with `set_error_handler()`.

```
set_error_handler(function ($no, $err, $file, $line)
{
    // do whatever you want to if an error of type E_WARNING occurs
}, E_WARNING);
```

Comment: Thanks. I added `error_reporting(1);` before the include statement but it's still not giving me an error message.

Comment: Try adding:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Update : I editied my php.ini file and this is now working. Any ideas about my first problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, go to:

`Start > Appserv > PHP Edit php.ini`

Find line : `display_errors Off` and change to `display_errors On`

`Save & Close`

`Start > AppServ > Apache Restart`